# SQL group by and having clause issue wrt count

Tags: sql

I have a below table Product
maker model type

```
A      1232  PC
A      1233  PC 
A      1276  Printer
A      1298  Laptop
A      1401  Printer
A      1408  Printer
A      1752  Laptop
B      1121   PC 
B      1750  Laptop
C      1321  Laptop
D      1288  Printer
D      1433  Printer
E      1260  PC
E      1434  Printer
E      2112  PC
E      2113  PC
```

I want to find out the makers who produce only one product type and more than one model.

The answer is

```
Maker Type
D        Printer
```

So far, I have written this query:

```
Select maker, type 
from product  
group by type, maker 
having count(model) > 1
```

It gives the below result:

maker type

```
A     Laptop
A     PC
A     Printer
D     Printer
E     PC
```

My question is how to write condition to get result for 1 type only ? as writing having count(type)=1 removes maker D which is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.Maker, p1.[Type]
FROM product p1
JOIN 
(
  Select maker
  from product  
  group by maker 
  having count(distinct model) > 1    
  AND count(distinct [type]) = 1
) p2
ON p1.MAKER = p2.MAKER
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.Maker, p1.[Type]
FROM product p1
WHERE maker in
(
  Select maker
  from product  
  group by maker 
  having count(distinct model) > 1    
  AND count(distinct [type]) = 1
)
```

Comment: The above query doesn't show the 'type' column.   The final answer should be Maker Type --> D Printer

Comment: SPOT ON ! Thanks so much !!

Comment: May I know how you solved it ? I had created The statement after JOIN but how did it work with the first select ?

Comment: First you needed to find the maker that fit your criteria, so I made that query to get your maker D. Then you needed to find the type for that maker, so I used the original table, selected type and maker, and filtered on the makers identified before. The query would also work looking like this :

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p1.Maker, p1.[Type]
FROM product p1
WHERE maker in
(
  Select maker
  from product  
  group by maker 
  having count(distinct model) > 1    
  AND count(distinct [type]) = 1
)`

Comment: Thanks, the second query is much easier to understand ! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Select maker, max(type) as type
from product  
group by maker 
having min(type) = max(type) and
       min(model) <> max(model);
```

Comment: Nope, the above query just returns one column of maker with 3 rows (A , B ,E) without type column and removes the maker D which is the right answer.

Comment: @PramTal . . . I misread the question.  I thought it said multiple types and multiple models.  So, I fixed it.  This should be the simplest way to express the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct maker, type from product 
group by maker having count(distinct model)>1 AND 
count(distinct type) = 1;
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.